# can the buyers or sellers in smart contract be the miner also?

Tags: smartcontracts

Can the buyers or sellers in the smart contracts be the miner also? Like someone be the player and also be the verifier?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your question. It feels like you had more context in mind when asking the question, but it was lost in brevity. If RedGrittyBrick's answer didn't resolve your question, please provide more context to clarify what you were interested in.

Answer (score 2):

> **Can the buyers or sellers in the smart contracts be the miner also?**

Yes.

> **Like someone be the player and also be the verifier?**

In Bitcoin, everyone verifies. All players are also verifiers. There are no players who are not verifiers. The miners do not have any special role in verification. Nobody depends on miners to verify anything.

The job performed by miners that is not performed by non-miners is a sequencing of transactions that results in the production of confirmations of those transactions. Confirmations are different from verification.